# string path is correct, but gives an error on .zip extract c#

Tags: c#, windows

Context: i have a zip file in %appdata%.lucaclient\java\java.zip but when I build the project it doesn't work.

strings:

```cs
string path = @"C:\%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\.lucaclient";
string downloadClientPath = @"C:\%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\.lucaclient\Client 1.8.8";
string downloadJavaPath = @"C:\%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\.lucaclient\java";
string extractJavaPath = @"C:\%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\.lucaclient\java\java.zip";
```

on click code:

```cs
private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(firstLaunch == true)
            {
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(extractJavaPath, downloadJavaPath);
            }
        }
```

[error after build, but path is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQCca.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to fill the userprofile path proberly.
try this function:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Roaming\.lucaclient";
string downloadClientPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Roaming\.lucaclient\Client 1.8.8";
string downloadJavaPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Roaming\.lucaclient\java";
string extractJavaPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Roaming\.lucaclient\java\java.zip";
```

Comment: and how do I do that? can you give me an example please? i don't have experience with c#

Comment: Updated it for you

Comment: it doesnt work like you said, but this works: you had to remove the extra roaming
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\.lucaclient"; thanks!

Comment: glad i could at least guide you in the right direction :)